# Content not showing well on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, responsive-design

I'm having issues with the web I'm working on mobile devices. In desktop looks perfect, also I resized the browser to the lowest width and still looks great, but on mobile is showing as a white big box to the right, like if is another content. [Mobile View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOhWy.png)

As I said before on desktop it looks perfect, even if I resize the browser to the lowest. [Desktop View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzIyL.png)

Honestly, I don't know what the problem is, I would appreciate the help a lot.

Comment: Looks like that header has min width, why dont you try and give it a fixed with of '100vh' so it doesnt ever overflow

Comment: Maybe it'd be better you post some code for can be analyzed.

Comment: put full code or "fiddle" this is not `JavaScript` issue, if this is clean design go with responsive framework like `Bootstrap` or if it is update to pre-existing design, please put some code. This is completely `CSS` issue

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, was this line `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`.

I changed the number of the inital-scale to 0.5 and it worked perfect, i dont understand why. I would appreciate if someone explane me the function of the initial-scale.

Thanks.